# Relative pronoun "où" for "une situation"

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

The relative pronoun *où* is used for place and time. Can it also be used in a metaphorical sense, such as "a situation where ..."?

> Étiez-vous jamais dans une situation **où** vous avez dû résoudre un conflit entre plusieurs personnes ?

Or do we have to use *dans laquelle*?

> Étiez-vous jamais dans une situation **dans laquelle** vous avez dû résoudre un conflit entre plusieurs personnes ?

If the usage of *où* in this manner is fine, it would be nice if you could give a few more examples like this as well. For example:

> La classe de physique est celle **où** je m'amuse à chaque fois.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idiomatic way to say the first example would be as follows (with the correct tense):

> Vous êtes-vous jamais retrouvé dans une situation où vous deviez résoudre un conflit entre plusieurs personnes ?

The use of "où" is the way to go; the duplicate use of "dans ... dans" is too much of a mouthful, if not ungrammatical.

---

While there is nothing grammatically wrong with the second example, it would be more natural to say (with more appropriate words):

> Les cours de physique, c'est ce que j'apprécie toujours beaucoup.

The use of "où" will be fully justified if the sentence goes something like:

> J'ai beaucoup apprécié le cours de physique où le professeur parlait de ...